# Kendo widgets/validator are being undefined in IE?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, internet-explorer-11

I am kind of at a loss here... I am having issues with Kendo and Internet Explorer.

I have a validator that I set up, I have stepped through my code, `<div id="validatorCheck">{content}</div>` exists in my DOM. When the user opens my editor, I initialize the validator.

```
$('#validatorCheck').kendoValidator({
                        //validate: function(e) {
                        //},
                        validateInput: function(e) {
                            if(e.valid == false && scrolledToElement == false){
                                scrolledToElement = true;
                                $('#externalEditor').animate({
                                    scrollTop: e.input.offset().top
                                }, 300, function() { 
                                    //Callback after animation
                                });
                            }
                        },
                        rules: {
                            endDateValidation: function(e) {
                                //console.log(e);
                                if (e.is('[data-role=datetimepicker]') && e[0].id == 'endTimeInput') {
                                    var endTimeValid = $('#endTimeInput').data('kendoDateTimePicker');
                                    var startTimeValid = $('#startTimeInput').data('kendoDateTimePicker');

                                    if (endTimeValid.value() < startTimeValid.value()) {
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                }
                                return true;
                            },
                            autoCompleteValidation: function(e){
                                if(e.is('[data-role=autocomplete]')){
                                    var autoCompleteComp = e.data('kendoAutoComplete');
                                    if(autoCompleteComp != undefined){
                                        if(e[0].attributes.hasOwnProperty('required') && (autoCompleteComp.value() == '' || autoCompleteComp.value() == null)){
                                            return false;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                return true;
                            }
                        },
                        messages: {
                            //hasItems: 'Owner Must Be Selected'
                            endDateValidation: 'End Time Must Be Greater Than Start Time',
                        }
                    });
```

Right after the above code, when I was stepping through this, I watched `$('#validatorCheck').data('kendoValidator')` and it was initialized. Then, when the user hits the save button, I call:

`$('#validatorCheck').data('kendoValidator').validate()`, however, now `$('#validatorCheck').data('kendoValidator')` is undefined and it crashes.

The editor never closed, nothing was destroyed, it is still in the DOM with a data-role of validator, which it got from my initialization in the code above, but it is undefined.

Spelling is correct, I even tried redownloading my version of KendoUI for fresh files, etc... but it doesn't do anything to help.

Chrome, Firefox, Edge, etc... all work fine. This issue only happens in IE (currently in version 11).

I am not sure if anyone knows anything about this bizarre issue, but I can't think of what it is that is going on or how to fix this.

Side note: a dropdownlist I have will do this too, where it will be undefined well after I initialized it, but only sometimes. The validator issue is happening all the time.

Comment: What exactly happens when the  user hits the Save button?

Comment: I bound the click event to save, the first thing that happens in the click function is: `if($('#validatorCheck').data('kendoValidator').validate()){//Do stuff}` and it fails at that if statement cuz $('#validatorCheck').data('kendoValidator') comes back as undefined... This happens after it was initialized as it gets initialized immediately when editor opens and save button has to be clicked after editor is opened and loaded.

Comment: Can you please try double quotes in all of your jQuery references? IE might be sensitive to that, which is the recommended syntax. For example: $("#validatorCheck").data("kendoValidator").validate()

Comment: That unfortunately did not fix it. This is such a frustrating issue, nothing about it makes sense :(.

Comment: Does this help? https://curtistimson.co.uk/post/jquery/understanding-jquery-data-storage/

Comment: And stepping through the entire thing when my editor opens, the Validator gets initialized, and is initialized the entire time until control comes back to me as I stepped through all executing code. but as soon as the save button is hit, it all the sudden can't get the validator anymore.

Comment: Telerik seems to set up validators differently. Can you try to replicate the programming model shown here? https://www.telerik.com/forums/kendo-validation-client-validation-on-ie-9

Comment: It is frustrating, but there must be an answer here. This issue seems to do more with jQuery than with IE or Kendo, per se. Don't give up--this is a solvable problem. If the Kendo link I gave above doesn't help then I will probably just with for others to chime in...

Comment: I just noticed that the $('#validator') element is saying '3.3.1' for its jquery property, but the version I included is 1.12.3.... Kendo does require 1.12.3 to be used, the mismatched versions MAY be the issue, but I am not holding my breath. But I don't know how it is getting 3.3.1 when the only jquery I loaded was 1.12.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168943/discussion-between-jazimov-and-tyler-dahle).

Answer (score 1):

This might be more of a jQuery version issue than an issue with Internet Explorer (IE), per se. Ensure that Kendo has access to the expected version of jQuery at runtime in IE.

Comment: Thanks--please let us know the definitive solution, once you have it. For example, did you end up getting the right version of jQuery to load for Kendo? Did you need to run two jQuery versions side-by-side to support your page's other needs?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out this was an issue with Internet Explorer and Salesforce Lightning Components.

Salesforce lightning components are supposed to be a self contained entity that you load all the scripts they need in the component, this included a JQuery script. In modern browsers, this worked fine. In Internet Explorer... the scripts from the Lightning Component leaked out onto the main page so I had two JQuery's loaded that ended up causing the issue.

Now that I know the issue, this may be better served on the Salesforce stack exchange, but I had no clue it was the lightning component being handled incorrectly by IE, I thought it was just some IE/Kendo issue.